# Selenium cannot get iframe

Tags: python, html, selenium, iframe

I am trying to retrieve the Job Description and Job Requirements from this link:
https://www.jobsbank.gov.sg/ICMSPortal/portlets/JobBankHandler/SearchDetail.do?id=JOB-2016-0008238

using selenium. This is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "https://www.jobsbank.gov.sg/ICMSPortal/portlets/JobBankHandler/SearchDetail.do?id=JOB-2016-0008238"
driver.get(url)
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="divMainJobDescription"]')
print len(iframes)
driver.switch_to_frame(iframes)
print driver.page_source
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\scraper.py", line 79, in
>   
>       main()   File "D:\Abigail MTI Projects\Singapore Skills\JobsBankScraper\jobsbank14012016_abi.py", line 74, in main
>       driver.switch_to_frame(iframes)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 537, in switch_to_frame
>       self._switch_to.frame(frame_reference)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\switch_to.py",
>   line 67, in frame
>       self._driver.execute(Command.SWITCH_TO_FRAME, {'id': frame_reference})   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 201, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 181, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) NoSuchFrameException: Message: Unable to locate frame: [object Object]
>   Stacktrace:
>       at FirefoxDriver.prototype.switchToFrame (file:///c:/users/mti_wl~1/appdata/local/temp/tmpwelh3x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10745)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/mti_wl~1/appdata/local/temp/tmpwelh3x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12551)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/mti_wl~1/appdata/local/temp/tmpwelh3x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12556)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/mti_wl~1/appdata/local/temp/tmpwelh3x/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12498)

Answer (score 0):

`iframes` is list, you need to switch to a single frame.

`driver.find_elements` return list while `driver.find_element` return single web element (note the 's' in element/s).

In addition, `divMainJobDescription` is not `iframe`, I believe you are looking for `frameJobDescription`

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("frameJobDescription")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the iframe, switch to that frame, and then you can start identifying other elements, like divs, which exist inside that frame. You need to specify the **iframe tag itself** and not an element inside the iframe.

So, instead of targeting a div immediately inside the frame like

```
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="divMainJobDescription"]')
```

target the iframe tag, then switch. (You can use the singular find_**element**_by_xpath if you want only one iframe.)

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@id="frameJobDescription"]')
driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
job_description = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divMainJobDescription"]')
```

Bonus: You can use other methods to target the iframe, such as finding the element by ID instead of writing the xpath, if you are only looking at IDs.

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('frameJobDescription')
```

If you need to get details in BOTH iframes during your script, you will need to take turns switching between frames.